# Dynamic ng-classes

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to accomplish this:

Short the `ng-click` actions by putting them inside a function in controller.

Right now I have `<div>` elements that contains pictures that I choose to load from file input,

each div contains an enlarge button, this button change the `ng-class` of the related `<div>` (some sort of wrapper for each img), the thing that annoys me is that I have too many `ng-class` attributes so I ended up with :

```
 <img class="zoomPhoto" ng-click="mgZoomIn{1}=\'invisible\';mgZoomOut{1}=\'visible\';ngImgUploadDiv{1}=\'imgUploadDivhover\';ngimgWrapper{1}=\'imgWrapperhover\';ngMainImg{1}=\'mainImghover\'" ng-class="mgZoomIn{1}" src="Images/1425524419_SEARCH.png" />
```

Now because I'm creating the divs dynamicly, I can't predict the index in {1}, also I know it's wrong to create function for each index, so what can i do?

Currently, the way it's written - it's working, I can load 7 photos, each with it's own index, it's just too much code in ng-click that annoys me.

here is an output result from loading 2 imgs:

output 1:

```
<img class="zoomPhoto ng-scope" ng-click="mgZoomIn0='invisible';mgZoomOut0='visible';ngImgUploadDiv0='imgUploadDivhover';ngimgWrapper0='imgWrapperhover';ngMainImg0='mainImghover'" ng-class="mgZoomIn0" src="Images/1425524419_SEARCH.png">
```

output 2:

```
<img class="zoomPhoto ng-scope" ng-click="mgZoomIn1='invisible';mgZoomOut1='visible';ngImgUploadDiv1='imgUploadDivhover';ngimgWrapper1='imgWrapperhover';ngMainImg1='mainImghover'" ng-class="mgZoomIn1" src="Images/1425524419_SEARCH.png">
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to do this (probably wrong):

```
app.controller('classChanger', ['$scope',
    function ($scope, $parse) {
        $scope.ChangeClass =
            function (index, isEnlarge) {
                var func = '';
                if (isEnlarge)
                    func = "function runtimeChangeClass () {ngZoomIn{0} ='invisible';ngZoomOut{0} ='visible';ngImgUploadDiv{0} ='imgUploadDivhover';ngimgWrapper{0} ='imgWrapperhover';ngMainImg{0} ='mainImghover';}";
                else
                    func = "function runtimeChangeClass () {ngZoomIn{0} ='visible';ngZoomOut{0} ='invisible';ngImgUploadDiv{0} ='';ngimgWrapper{0} ='';ngMainImg{0}='';}";

                func = func.format(index);
                $scope.runtimeChangeClass = $scope.$eval(func);

                $scope.runtimeChangeClass();

            };
    }]);
```

and it's not working, but generally, this is what i'm trying to do.

Comment: `ng-class="mgZoomIn{1}"` is `{}` valid?

Comment: I created a string.format(..) function so i load the index, create the element and then compile it

Comment: where are you using `mgZoomIn0` varialbe ?

Comment: in this case - on the very same img element, look at the end of the element, for the others, i use them on other elements that wrapping the main img element (not the enlarge button that in the outputs)

Comment: you can create a function `mgZoom` in you controller with all these variables as parameters.

Comment: I have added code that i tried to make, some sort of what you have suggested, it didn't worked when i tried it, probably implemented wrong :S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was talking about something like this :

```js
$scope.changeClass = function(mgZoomIn, mgZoomOut, ngImgUploadDiv,
  ngimgWrapper, ngMainImg) {
  this.mgZoomIn = mgZoomIn,
    this.mgZoomOut = mgZoomOut,
    this.ngImgUploadDiv = ngImgUploadDiv,
    this.ngimgWrapper = ngimgWrapper,
    this.ngMainImg = ngMainImg;

  console.log(this.mgZoomIn);
  return this;

};
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! as i said, i'm a beginner with angular, i didn't know "this" will reffer to the current controller block :)